# My AD users are not updating using powershell and csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have read many articles and I've been able to come up with a code that works for what i want to do: I want to be able to update my AD USERS and if a the attribute is blank on my csv it should be removed on the users attribute

```
$Users = Import-CSV "C:\Users\tolulope\Desktop\Tolu AD\ADusers2.csv"

foreach($User  in $Users  )
{

    Write-host "$user"
    Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -like '$user'"|Set-ADUser -Replace @{
    givenName = "$User.givenName";
    sn = "$User.sn";
    c = "$User.c";
    cn = "$User.cn";
    company = "$User.company";
    co = "$User.co";
    countryCode = "$User.countryCode" ;
    department = "$User.department";
    displayName = "$User.displayName";
    mobile = "$User.mobile";
    name = "$User.name";
    userPrincipalName = "$User.userPrincipalName"
    telephoneNumber = "$User.telephoneNumber";
    streetAddress = "$User.streetAddress";
    st = "$User.st";
    postalCode = "$User.postalCode";
    physicalDeliveryOfficeName = "$User.physicalDeliveryOfficeName";
    manager = "$User.manager";
    employeeID = "$User.employeeID";
    title = "$User.title";
    l = "$User.l";
    homePhone = "$User.homePhone";
    mail = "$User.mail";

}

}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: What is the problem / what does not work?

Comment: It doesnt update, No changes is reflected in the AD @Patrick

Comment: Your `Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -like '$user" ` cannot work. `$user` is a complex object, you cannot use `-like` on that. Try `Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$(user.userPrincipalName)'" ` (or some other unambiguous property, i.e. *not* "DisplayName")

Comment: @Tomalak just tried it now, but it's telling me the ```Set-ADUser: Parameter is incorrect```

Comment: One step after the other. First make sure, that `Get-ADUser` actually returns a user for each row of your input. As soon as that works, try to update a single property, not all of them. As soon as *that* works, keep adding more properties until you find which one it does not like. Inspect your data to find out why, maybe something is off in one of those columns.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks it worked well, issue now is that I have blank values in my csv and I'll like to remove attribute values of user with blanks in my CSV

Comment: When you write a blank value to the AD user object's attribute, is that not the same as removing the attribute?

Comment: It is my understanding that in order to remove property values for an AD object, you need to use the `-Clear` parameter on these properties. You can comma separate the properties you want blanked out like `Set-ADUser -Clear Manager, Description, Department`.. I'm not sure if setting these properties to `$null` will work, never tried that.